# R Shiny app published to R Studio Connect missing www files

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am new to Shiny apps and I am publishing to my company's R Studio Connect server.  I have just 2 files in www in the same directory where app.R is located: a css file and a company logo svg.  The app functions perfectly on my desktop, but for some reason the paths to the two files in www breaks when published to the server.

Here are the relevant snippets where I reference those two files:

###### CSS File

```
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="/customized.css")
),
```

###### Logo SVG Image

```
titlePanel( div(column(width=8, h2("App Title")),
                column(width=4, tags$img(src="/logo.svg", width="120px", align="right"))),
                windowTitle="App Title"),
```

I check all the files to publish like this:

[image]

I'm not setting a working directory or anything, so I'm not sure why the relative paths would break when they work on desktop.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: `/logo.svg` is the root directory, not the directory of your app

Comment: Thanks @rawr.  What would be a relative path that would work on desktop and on the server? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: i would think it should be `www/logo.svg`, not sure how `/logo.svg` is working on your machine unless you have files saved at `/`, what does `file /logo.svg` return in your terminal

Comment: I actually got it sorted just now.  The www folder seems to be implied in the fluidPage object whenever specifying a path.  I got it to work just now by removing the leading forward slash (e.g., "logo.svg" instead of "/logo.svg").  Now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at other examples I noticed some did not include the leading forward slash in the file path.  I removed that and it works now on the server.  As far as I can tell, the www folder is implied as the root folder for any relative paths in the UI.

```
tags$head(
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="customized.css")
),
```